# Gracefully unsubscribe from redis at exit

Tags: ruby, redis, application-restart, hiredis

I have a ruby program which listens to a redis channel:

```
module Listener
  class << self
    def listen
      redis.subscribe "messaging" do |on|
        on.message do |_, msg|
          Notify.about(msg)
        end
      end
    end

    def redis
      @redis ||= Redis.new(driver: :hiredis)
    end
  end
end
```

Every time I deploy the app I restart the process with

```
kill -15 listener-pid
```

But [Airbrake](https://airbrake.io/) notifies me about the `SignalException: SIGTERM` with the following backtrace

```
/gems/hiredis-0.6.1/lib/hiredis/ext/connection.rb:19 in read
/gems/hiredis-0.6.1/lib/hiredis/ext/connection.rb:19 in read
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/hiredis.rb:54 in read
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:262 in block in read
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:250 in io
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:261 in read
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:136 in block (3 levels) in call_loop
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:135 in loop
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:135 in block (2 levels) in call_loop
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:231 in block (2 levels) in process
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:367 in ensure_connected
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:221 in block in process
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:306 in logging
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:220 in process
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:134 in block in call_loop
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:280 in with_socket_timeout
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:133 in call_loop
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:43 in subscription
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:12 in subscribe
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:2765 in _subscription
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:2143 in block in subscribe
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58 in block in synchronize
/usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214 in mon_synchronize
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58 in synchronize
/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:2142 in subscribe
```

Is it possible to restart the listener process gracefully so I wont receive SIGTERM errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [pubsub](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/v3.3.3/examples/pubsub.rb) example in [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb)

After I added `trap('SIGTERM') { exit }` the problem was fixed

Now my listener class looks like this:

```
module Listener
  class << self
    def listen
      trap('SIGTERM') { exit }

      redis.subscribe "messaging" do |on|
        on.message do |_, msg|
          Notify.about(msg)
        end
      end
    end

    def redis
      @redis ||= Redis.new(driver: :hiredis)
    end
  end
end
```